# I need to restart a .NET WPF Application from a VB6 COM automation using CreateObject()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, com

I have a working application where I had to replace a VB6 COM Server with a .NET in C#. It is instantiated by a VB6 Client using CreateObject() ProgID and CLSID through the regitry. An Automation Interface is supported and all works fine with the communication between VB6 and C# .NET.

My problem is I need to restart the Application written in C# .NET and it will not restart after being shut down. 
The restart works with the old version written is VB6.

In the VB6 code it would shutdown the Server by assigning the Interface and object to 'Nothing'.
i.e. MySvrObj.AutoIntFce = Nothing
i.e. MySvrObj = Nothing.

To Shutdown my C#.NET Server I had to replace the "= Nothing" with a method to the Automation Interface that would eventually call Automation.Current.Shutdown(). This all worked and the Application would shutdown. 
My problem is I cannot restart the Server after shutting it down.

I originally started chasing the error "Cannot Create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain." From the Code below this happens on the line "app = new App()".

```
       //Thread to start Application
        Thread UIThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();

            System.Windows.Application.Current.Run();
        }
        );

        UIThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        UIThread.Start();//Start application run thread

        while (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }           
        return;
```

I have tried to re-run the existing app in the same thread but when I get to the line System.Windows.Application.Current.Run() the "Current" is null. I then tried to execute app.Run() and the message is "Cannot Run Multiple Items"

I feel like I do not have a handle on an underlying issue that is causing me to chase my tail. Any explanation or solution to my problem would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Here is the VB Shutdown process that utilizes the .NET portion of the interface (IDotNet) and also assigns "=Nothing" to the interface that would shutdown the old VB6 Server fine. The old VB6 application also created the same excel process.

```
Friend Sub Shutdown()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim ShutDownDotNet As IDotNet

If Not (mimMaint Is Nothing) Then
    Set ShutDownDotNet = mimMaint.DotNet
    ShutDownDotNet.QuitDotNet
    If Not (mimMaint.Job Is Nothing) Then
        Set mimMaint.Job.ProgressClient = Nothing
        Set mimMaint = Nothing
        If Not (mimtToolbar Is Nothing) Then
            mimtToolbar.GetButton("Maintenance").Enabled = False
        End If
        mblnAvail = False
    End If
End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   If Err.Number = 462 Then
     Resume Next
   Else
     gmcMessaging.ReportError "Maintenance::Shutdown", Err.Number, Err.Description
     Resume Next
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example, including the shutdown code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The application has a pretty involved shutdown process. It creates an Excel process. That may be my next step is to duplicate the whole COM object simplified and registering it with a different CLSID and see if it works. This will tell me if something is stuck in memory breaking the separation I am expecting from COM. I was wondering if having mixed managed and un-managed client/server's and if  they are existing in the same AppDomain where this would not be the case with just un-managed client and server. I am trying to make sure I am not doing anything illegal.